# Segmentation Fault Error In C, Function Won't Return Value

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

I am making a program that searches for a card name and outputs the card's price based on its position in an array. The program finds the card just fine, but the issue is with the spell check, the function should return a value that indicates that the card was not found in the array, but every time a card's name is misspelled, the program outputs "Segmentation Fault" and exits.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define COUNTOF(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof( (x)[0]))

int search_1(string card);
string cards_1[5] = {"card1", "card2", "card3", "card4", "card5"};

int main(void){
    string card1 = get_string("Card Purchased: ");

    if(search_1(card1) == -1){
        printf("CARD NOT FOUND\n");
    }

    else{
        printf("CARD FOUND\n");
    }
}

int search_1(string card){
    int x = 0;

    while(x < COUNTOF(cards_1)){
        int cardcmp = strcmp(cards_1[x], card);

        if(cardcmp == 0){
            return x;
        }
        x++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: `else if(search_1(card1) != -1)` Not a reason to crash, but this should be just `else`. As written, it is redundant and it runs `search_1` a second time.

Comment: For `x==5..19` you will feed a `NULL` pointer into `strcmp` which is not what you are supposed to do. Fir index 20..79 or similar, you will pass whatever you find in memory that you are not even supposed to read.

Comment: @AdamYounes CS50 is teaching terrible techniques regarding strings; I'll be a better C programmer if you abandon their foolish "string" type and just always think about the pointers directly.  As to the sizeof issue, a common macro is: `#define COUNTOF(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof( (x)[0]))` that gives the number of *items* in the thing, not the number of *bytes*.

Comment: @SteveFriedl Worth mentioning the caveat that the macro has limitations.  It works for arrays but not for pointers. And when an array is passed into a function, it decays to a pointer.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons, yes, that's worth mentioning.

Comment: Without the question being reopened, it's hard to show real code, but use the above `COUNTOF` macro in your `search_1` function:  `while (x < COUNTOF(cards_1))` ...

Comment: @SteveFriedl The same error occurs after the addition of the `COUNTOF` macro.

Comment: If this is failing, there's something else going on.  It's well worth your time to dive in with a debugger to find out exactly where it's dying.

Comment: The above code (with minor modifications for not having cs50.h) works fine for me, so I wonder if the code in the post *exactly* matches what you're running?

Comment: @SteveFriedl Believe it or not this was it. `COUNTOF` was misspelled when I called it in my program. Thank you so much for the help! So is it considered generally good practice to define a separate function rather than using the existing one, or was it a problem with the specific library I was using?

Comment: @AdamYounes "separate function rather than using the existing one" - I'm not sure what you're referring to?

Comment: @SteveFriedl oh, my bad, I meant defining 'COUNTOF' as having the same purpose as 'sizeof' rather than just using 'sizeof'. Was that because of an issue with the way that the original function interacted with memory?

Comment: @AdamYounes - No, this is strictly about your understanding of C. `sizeof` is part of the C language that evaluates as the number of *bytes* in a thing, but you were using it to mean how many *items*.  The number you cared about was 5 - which is how many *items* there were, but you were simply using the wrong mechanism. the `COUNTOF` macro takes the total number of bytes (lets  call it 5 * 4 = 20) divided by the size of ONE of those things, giving the number of items, not bytes. This is worth studying carefully.

Comment: I ran your code, it does not segfault for misspelling.  What is the exact input to cause segfault?